# Vue Router doesn't preserve URLs entered into the address bar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli, vuejs3, vue-router4

So I've got a Vue Router running in history mode. It works perfectly when clicking `<router-links>`, but I can't get address bar navigations to 'stick'. The address always reverts back to the previous URL, despite loading the correct page content.

You can replicate this yourself by running `vue create projectName` and choosing `Manually select features` -> `Router` -> `Vue 3.x` -> `Use history mode (Y)`. This creates the example project below.

If you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/about`, the About view loads. Correct.

[image]

Now if you type `http://localhost:8080/`, the Home view loads, but the URL reverts to `/about`!

[image]

And if you type `http://localhost:8080/about` again, the exact opposite happens.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Vue Router 4?

Comment: Can you show us your routes (code)?

Comment: Sure, they're the default routes that Vue CLI generates. https://jsfiddle.net/53fuLqr2/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug exclusively in [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com). Popular browsers show the expected behaviour with Vue Router, even other Chromium browsers.

I really should've checked that to begin with. Hope this helps someone else, though!